# Apache Camel Cannot acquire lock within xxx millis. Will skip the file

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I recently started working with Camel to ftp some files to a remote server. There is quite a large amount of data that needs to be transferred (~5 GB). In order to have a fast delivery of that data, I set up Camel to work with a couple of threads.
My configuration class looks as follows:

```
@Component
public class FTPCamelRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Value("${camel.zip.input}")
    private String inputDirectory;

    public void configure() {
        from(inputDirectory + "?recursive=true&readLock=changed&readLockTimeout=3000&readLockCheckInterval=500&readLockMinAge=30s")
            .onException(Exception.class).maximumRedeliveries(3).retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN).continued(true).end()
            .threads(10)
            .log("Uploading file ${file:name}")
            .to("{{camel.zip.output}}")
            .log("Uploaded file ${file:name} complete.");
    }
}
```

Definition of the camel zip input and output folder looks as follows:

```
camel.zip.input=file\\:/Temp/
camel.zip.output=ftp://host:21?username=xxx&password=yyy&binary=true
```

When running my code, **all** the files are transferred. However, I repeatedly keep getting a readLock timeout on multiple files (I'd say about 10% of the files that need to be processed, throw this timeout). I'm assuming that some threads try to lock a file that is already being processed by another thread, hence the readLock timeouts on that file. However, this hardly seems appropriate behavior for a threading application. Is there a way to get around this?

Thnx in advance

Comment: I haven't worked with `apache-camel` before but would it be possible for you to use some kind a blocking queue in between such that threads can de-queue the file names in the queue. This will ensure that one thread works only with one file.

Comment: That could be a possible solution for this problem. We opted for camel since it is very flexible with lots of configuration options and quite easy to use.
I'm not that familiar with queues myself, but I'd certainly consider it an option if the project were still in a startup phase.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to spawn threads yourself. Unless told otherwise Camel will read all files in your from-directory and process each in a separate thread anyway. Your read lock is probably due to some or all of the other threads trying to access the files which have already been locked by the first thread.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's what I'm thinking as well. It seems like this is more of a bug with apache-camel itself, than anything else.

I'm just wondering if there is any way I can get past this easily, perhaps by changing some camel config option? I tried playing around with the locking strategies, but none of them seem to fix the issue.

Comment: What I mean is that the file-component and its derivatives (e.g. ftp or sftp) are multithreaded in themselves. Thus there should not really be a need for you to use the treads DSL. The read locks you are getting are happening before your own threading which suggests that you are continously writing files to the directory from which you are polling, correct? If the route cannot achieve an exclusive lock the file will be skipped. To avoid this you should write the files to a temp-dir and then move them to the directory you are using as the from-endpoint afterwards.

Comment: Aha!
You're right. My spring-batch processing is generating files and writes these to a directory. This same directory is used as the from-endpoint for my camel processing.
For this exact reason, I used the "changed" readlock, with a readLockMinAge of 30 seconds. My spring batch processing should definitely not require longer than that to write files to that directory, but perhaps I'm overlooking something there.
Adding the "threads(10)" to the whole camel processing did speed up the ftp significantly however (my test-runs took about 1/3 of the time they used to take without threads).